# Isomorphic matrix algebras with non-isomorphic C*-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $C^{\ast}$-algebras such that their matrix algebras, $M_2(A)$ and $M_2(B)$, are $\ast$-isomorphic $C^\ast$-algebras.

**Question 1**: Are $A$ and $B$ isomorphic $C^\ast$-algebras?

In a related case, let $X$ and $Y$ be locally compact topological spaces.

**Question 2**: Are there non-homeomorphic $X$ and $Y$ such that $M_2\big(C_0(X)\big)$ and $M_2\big(C_0(Y)\big)$ are $\ast$-isomorphic $C^\ast$-algebras?

It is obvious that "2" is not a forced condition.

Comment: I believe there is an example (due to Rordam?) of a C* algebra $A$ such that $M_2(A)$ is stable, but $A$ is not. So $B = A\otimes\mathcal{K}$ and $A$ would be counterexamples to Q1. Not sure about Q2.

Comment: The reference is http://www.math.ku.dk/~rordam/manus/encyc.pdf Paragraph 4.

Comment: @prahlad-vaidyanathan Thanks for your guide and partial answer.

Comment: Maybe one of you guys could post an answer so that the question does not go unanswered? I know Mikael's construction is convoluted so the answer cannot be totally explicit, but it would still be nice to have something.

Comment: I think the answer to Q2 is also negative since the center of $M_2(C(X))$ is $C(X)$.

Comment: Thanks to comments of users, "prahlad-vaidyanathan" and "adrián-gonzález-pérez", my question has answered.

Comment: An overkill answer for the second question:
For commutative C*-algebras A,B we have $Cu(A)\cong Cu(B)$ iff $A\cong B$. Now, use the fact that $Cu(M_2(A))=Cu(A)$ to get a negative answer to the second question.

Comment: @ShirlyGeffen: That is a really nice application of the Cuntz-semigroup, nice!! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(after a couple years, I'm posting a summary of what was said in the comments so that the question does not remain unanswered)*

The answer to both questions is no.

In [this paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=rordam+stability+of+C*+algebras+is+not+a+stable+property&btnG=), Rordam shows that there exists a C$^*$-algebra $B$ such that $B$ is not stable while $M_2(B)$ is. So we can take $A=B\otimes K(H)$. Now
$$
M_2(A)\simeq M_2(B)\otimes K(H)\simeq M_2(B).
$$
But $A\not\simeq B$.

For the second question, if $M_2(C_0(X))\simeq M_2(C_0(Y))$ then both have equal Cuntz semigroup. But since the cuntz semigroup of $M_2(A)$ agrees with that of $A$, we get that $C_0(X)$ and $C_0(Y)$ have equal Cuntz semigroup; being abelian, we obtain $C_0(X)\simeq C_0(Y)$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.